# Windows Forms exe file works on My PC by not on others PC

Tags: c#, .net, dll, windows-forms-designer

I am building a windows form application in C# .Net, and I am using reportviewer and using RDLC file in the project. The build works fine and exe works as expected on my PC by doesn't work on Any other PC. Other PC is able to connect to all the required data objects.

while opening the Exe on other PC it crashes, when I remove the ReportViewer from build then the build works fine. Any suggestion how we can resolve this.

Comment: rdlc needs a runtime installation to work. impossible to tell without detailed exception information, but likely that [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496) is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Check required .net version available on machine.